# Solution to a quadratic matrix formula

Tags: quadratics, matrix-equations

I have vectors $z, a \in \mathbb{R}^N$, and symmetric, positive-definite matrices $A, \Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$. Both $A, \Sigma$ are covariance matrices.

I am given $z, a, A$ and want to solve for the unknown $\Sigma$.

I have a quadratic equation that looks like the following:
$$
\Sigma - A^{T} \Sigma^{-1} A = (z - a)(z - a)^{T}
$$
How should I solve this equation?

Comment: Must $\Sigma$ be symmetric positive definite also ?

Comment: Yes, it is a covariance matrix.

Comment: You should add this information in your question.

Comment: Thank you. Could you help me with my question?

Comment: As covariance matrices, $A$ and $\Sigma$ it should be only semi positive definite ? Right ?

Comment: But you assume that $\Sigma^{-1}$ exists, therefore $\Sigma$ is indeed psd.

Comment: Most covariance matrices are positive-definite. "Semi" is a rare case.

Answer (score 1):

What follows gives a method for the approximation of the solution.

Let us call $v=z-a$, giving equation :

$$\Sigma - A \Sigma^{-1} A = vv^{T}\tag{1}$$

(I have dropped the "T" symbol on $A$).

Comparison of (1) with :

$$A - A A^{-1} A = 0\tag{2}$$

has made me think that we could look for a solution of the form :

$$\Sigma=A+E\tag{3}$$

with an "error term" $E$.

Plugging (3) into (1) :

$$A+E-A(A+E)^{-1}A=vv^T \ \ \iff \ \ A+E-A(A(I+A^{-1}E))^{-1}A=vv^T$$

$$A+E-A(I+\underbrace{A^{-1}E}_D)^{-1}A^{-1}A=vv^T \ \ \iff \ \ A+E-A(I-D+D^2+...)=vv^T$$

If, in the last parenthesis, we keep only the first 2 terms, we will obtain :

$$E+AD=vv^T \ \ \iff \ \ E+AA^{-1}E=vv^T \ \ \iff \ \ E=\frac12vv^T\tag{4}$$

Therefore, plugging (4) into (3), we will the following approximation :

$$\Sigma\approx A+\frac12vv^T$$

I have tested it on a computer : this appoximation is rather good under the condition that the series $I-D+D^2+...$ converges, i.e. that $A^{-1}$ is small enough...

We can get a better approximation by taking into account a third term in this series, giving :

$$\Sigma\approx A+\frac12vv^T+\frac18 vv^T A^{-1} vv^T$$

Using this formula, in a good part of cases, numerical experiments show a small  discrepancy between the LHS and the RHS  (around $10^{-3}$).

---

Besides, looking for an exact solution, I have explored different tracks. Two of them look interesting :

1) Let $u \in v^{\perp}$ (the hyperplane of vectors orthogonal to $v$).

Left multiplying (1) by $u^T$ and right multiplying it by $u$ gives $0$ on the RHS. Therefore

$$u^T\Sigma u = u^TA^{T} \Sigma^{-1}Au$$

i.e., the two quadratic forms coincide on this hyperplane.

2) Matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}\Sigma&A\\A&\Sigma\end{pmatrix}$$

has the LHS of (1) for its "Schur complement".

Comment: Thank you for the approximate solution! I also thought about the Schur complement method, but wasn't able to find the exact solution...

Comment: I have just added the "second order approximation". One should exploit the fact (like in approach 1) that the RHS is a rank-one matrix. I am convinced that there are cases where this equation has no solution. But how can we prove it ?